# Kentico tapping into Page not Found event

Tags: events, kentico

My task is to log exception and page not found in our database, from inside a Kentico project. For page not found, i need to tap into "CMSRequestEvents.End.After" event. This event receives sender and event args. How do i crack event args and find page not found related stuff? Since this event gets fired for all the requests, I need to handle only "page not found" and log it. `SystemEvents.Exception.Execute` gets fired when an exception happens and page not found is not an exception. We are using Kentico version 7.

```
[CustomHandleError]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
    private class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called automatically when the application starts
        /// </summary>
        public override void Init()
        {
            // Assign custom handlers to the appropriate events
            SystemEvents.Exception.Execute += System_Exception_Execute;
            CMSRequestEvents.End.After += Request_End_After;
        }

        private void System_Exception_Execute(object sender, SystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var exception = e.Exception;
                var errorloggerHelper = new ErrorLoggerHelper();
                errorloggerHelper.LogError(exception);
            }
            catch
            {
                //do nothing 
            }
        }

        private void Request_End_After(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //since this gets called for each request, HANDLE only "page not found" and log

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that by "our database" you mean database other than the Kentico's one.
As Kentico already logs "Page Not Found" events I'd suggest attaching to the `EventLogInfo.TYPEINFO.Events.Insert.After` event and filtering by `EventCode=="PAGENOTFOUND"` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Handling+object+events).

Screenshot (v8):
[image]

Another option would be utilizing [custom error pages](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Creating+custom+error+handling+pages).

Comment: Thank you! This is (`EventLogInfo.TYPEINFO.Events.Insert.After`) what i was looking for. We have a pagenotfound page on the cms side, but i didn't want to tap into it via PortalTemplate page.